# Creating a trigger that replaces null values in an insert with values already present in the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table, known as `Fruit_Veg_Product_Table` which is used to contain the characteristics of certain fruit and vegetable stock.

The table has the following columns:

```
Product_ID
Product_Type
Product_Name
Product_Colour
Product_Price
Product_In_Sale
Product_Stock_Level
Product_Height
Product_Width
Product_Depth
Product_Package_Height
Product_Package_Width
Product_Package_Depth
```

When a new product is inserted into the table, sometimes the product is inserted without any dimensions (the columns from `Product_Height` all the way to `Product_Package_Depth`). In this circumstance, the dimensions are entered as NULL.

I am in need of a SQL Server trigger that will replace all the NULL values from the attempted insert with the values corresponding to products that are already stored in the table which share a common `Product_Type` with the product that is being entered.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are multiple matching products and the dimensions don't match?

Comment: Why not stop people from inserting `NULL` in the first place? Or, if fruits have set dimensions, store them elsewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I probably should have mentioned that actually, good question! You can assume that products in this case are all the same size if they share a Product_Type, which I imagine will make this easier.

Comment: This looks like a normalisation issue. If dimensions can be reliably inferred from product type they should be in the product type table

Comment: @Larnu I have brought up this approach before, apparently I have not been granted adequate permission to make new tables or I would have done this myself. Office politics!

Comment: Then pass it onto someone that can. If you can create a trigger, but not fix the design, the issue is with whomever can fix the design; making a trigger can only make this worse in the long run.

Comment: Putting business logic in triggers is a big no, no! I discovered that the hard way many years ago and don't want you to fell the same pain. It will cause all kinds of maintenance issues. Please try to put all business logic in your business layer.

Comment: As the others have said, this is path that will not end well. But if you need help, you need to make an effort. You need to define what logic is used to replace null values in the zero (yes), 1, or many (yes) rows that are inserted and which row is used as the source of replacement information for each new row. No one knows your schema, your keys, your grouping logic, etc. Without additional information, this will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers have an INSERTED logical table that can be used to join the inserted row data back to the physical table.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Fruit_Veg_Product_Table_Trg
ON dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table
FOR INSERT
AS
UPDATE dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table
SET Product_Package_Height = ca.Product_Package_Height,
    Product_Package_Width = ca.Product_Package_Width,
    Product_Package_Depth = ca.Product_Package_Depth
FROM dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           Product_Package_Height,
           Product_Package_Width,
           Product_Package_Depth
    FROM dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table AS fvpt
    WHERE dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table.Product_Type = fvpt.Product_Type
          AND Product_Package_Height IS NOT NULL
          AND Product_Package_Width IS NOT NULL
          AND Product_Package_Depth IS NOT NULL
) AS ca
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE INSERTED.Product_ID = dbo.Fruit_Veg_Product_Table.Product_ID
          AND INSERTED.Product_Package_Height IS NULL
          AND INSERTED.Product_Package_Width IS NULL
          AND INSERTED.Product_Package_Depth IS NULL
);

GO
```